# needed packages to run autoreconf and configure on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, autotools, autoreconf

What are the `.deb` packages needed to run these commands on a debian wheezy Linux?

```
cd software_that_builds_with_autotools
autoreconf --install &&\
./configure --prefix=/opt/foo/bar &&\
make && make install
```

I tried installing the following, but it still says it is lacking `aclocal`:

```
apt-get install binutils make csh g++ sed gawk autoconf autotools-dev

Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ``aclocal`` is found in the ``automake`` package

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If you want to turn it into an answer yourself, I will accept it: `sudo apt-get install binutils make csh g++ sed gawk autoconf automake autotools-dev`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use

```
sudo apt-get install binutils make csh g++ sed gawk autoconf automake autotools-dev
```